# How to scraping the html text using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get text `"General (8)"` shown in below HTML code using selenium webdriver but kept running into issues. Any input is highly appreciated. Thanks.

my code:

```
test1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id = 'General'][@role = 'presentation']").text
print(test1)
```

returns null

HTML:

```
<li class="" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false">
     <div class="extend_clickable" tabindex="0">
          <input id="General" role="presentation" name="General" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
          General (8)
          <label for="General" role="presentation"></label>
     </div>
</li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *returns null*? There is no such type in Python as `null`... What is actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` node is **always empty**. It means it cannot contain any child nodes (including text nodes). What you want is a text sibling of `input` which you can get as text content of parent `div`:

```
test1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="extend_clickable"]').text.strip()
```

Comment: This method works. Thank you. Please see my further question down below

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided to print the text **General (8)** you have to extract it from the `<div class="extend_clickable"` *tag*, as the *text* is not within `<input>` *tag* and you can use the following code block using *Python's* [`splitlines()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_splitlines.htm) method as follows :

```
all_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@role='checkbox']/div[@class='extend_clickable']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
myText = all_text.splitlines()
print(myText[1])
```

Console Output :

```
  General (8)
```

---

### Update

As per @Andersson's counter question/comment the following screenshot should address and answer all the queries.

[image: splitlines]

Comment: Is there any reason to make the code so complicated by using `innerHTML`? :) Note that your code will **NOT** return desired text output, but HTML of `input` node instead

Comment: Manipulating _HTML_ through _Python_ libraries are far easier through `innerHTML` with respect to the struggle you face through `.text`. Though out of scope the purpose of `.text` is completely different. Note that the code I provided is **proven** and **working** :)

Comment: You must be joking :))) No, I'm seriously. You want to find element, get it's innerHTML, split it into list of strings and get required string by its index instead of simply  get text content with `text` property?! As for your *proven and working*: `div` has 5 child nodes (empty string, input, non-empty string, lable, spaces). Index `1` will return **the input node**! Check again. And could you also specify the "purpose of `.text`"? It might be interesting for the whole Community :)

Comment: @Andersson Sir, Checkout my answer update and let me know if any further counter questions :)

Comment: Your code provided in answer doesn't match the code on screenshot. I mean `all_text` variable defined differently. Try the same with your initial code

Comment: Can you help me to understand your counter question please? Whatever `get_attribute("innerHTML")` is supposed to return have been put into `all_text` to invoke `splitlines()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: On screenshot you just pass the string into `all_text` while in code you use `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@role='checkbox']/div[@class='extend_clickable']").get_attribute("innerHTML")`. Values of these variables are different!

Comment: @Andersson Sir, Thanks for raising the doubt. IMO, it will be **identical**. But I am afraid as I don't have a way to prove it either. Can you help me to validate and confirm it?

Comment: You can try: 1) open webDriver instance from Pythone shell (e.g. ChromeDriver) 2) Right click on page body  opened in browser 3) Click Inspect 4) Right click on `<body>` node in DOM 5) Choose "Edit as HTML" option 6) Replace current HTML with HTML provided by OP 7) Close dev panel 8) Execute your code

Comment: @Andersson Sir, With all the due respect, IMO, that shouldn't be an ideal way to check the code through `DOM manipulation`

Comment: Not the ideal of course. Ideal is to get URL of relevant page. But anyway my way is much more reliable than just to pass your own string as HTML source

Comment: @Andersson Sir, How dare can I challenge the person who taught me _Selenium_ :) Of-coarse your way should work. But I believe to be safer `innerHTML` is the way as we can easily manipulate through `split()` , `splitlines()` and `regex`